# Does Wildfly deploy multiple WAR in one EAR as just one container?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, wildfly, wildfly-8

I know two WAR in same EAR is sharing HTTP session on wildfly 8+.
Here is two WAR. One WAR is copy of another's. And I failed deploy on wildfly 8, but success on wildfly 9 CR1. wildfly 9 print lots of logs such as below

> 2015-05-18 15:56:03,114 DEBUG
>   [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping]
>   Rejected bean name 'mvcUrlPathHelper': no URL paths identified
>   2015-05-18 15:56:03,114 DEBUG
>   [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping]
>   Rejected bean name
>   'org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping#0':
>   no URL paths identified 2015-05-18 15:56:03,115 DEBUG
>   [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping]
>   Rejected bean name
>   'org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#1':
>   no URL paths identified 2015-05-18 15:56:03,115 DEBUG
>   [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping]
>   Rejected bean name
>   'org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping#1':
>   no URL paths identified 2015-05-18 15:56:03,115 DEBUG
>   [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping]
>   Rejected bean name 'dataSource': no URL paths identified 2015-05-18
>   15:56:03,115 DEBUG
>   [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping]
>   Rejected bean name 'dataSourceForSMS': no URL paths identified
>   2015-05-18 15:56:03,115 DEBUG
>   [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping]
>   Rejected bean name 'txManager': no URL paths identified 2015-05-18
>   15:56:03,115 DEBUG
>   [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping]
>   Rejected bean name 'txManagerForSMS': no URL paths identified
>   2015-05-18 15:56:03,115 DEBUG
>   [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping]
>   Rejected bean name 'sqlSessionFactory': no URL paths identified
>   2015-05-18 15:56:03,116 DEBUG
>   [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping]
>   Rejected bean name 'sqlSessionFactoryForSMS': no URL paths identified
>   2015-05-18 15:56:03,116 DEBUG
>   [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping]
>   Rejected bean name 'sqlSession': no URL paths identified 2015-05-18
>   15:56:03,116 DEBUG
>   [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping]
>   Rejected bean name 'sqlSessionForSMS': no URL paths identified
>   2015-05-18 15:56:03,116 DEBUG
>   [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping]
>   Rejected bean name 'txAdvice': no URL paths identified

........and so on.....

So i guess, wildfly had deployed tow WAR in one EAR as one container. and conflict bean name on container(spring container).

is that correct?

if correct, how can i deploy multiple WAR each container using wildfly HTTP session sharing?

Comment: Does your EAR contain just the two WAR files and nothing else?

Comment: @SteveC yes. EAR contains just two WAR.

Comment: @SteveC yes. EAR contains just two WAR. i get some key that destoed classes had loaded in one class loading repository. So Maybe ignored class that has same full class name include package name load.

Comment: In that case each web module (WAR) will be completely isolated from each other. ie. They cannot "see" any of each others classes or other resources because they each have their own class loader.

Comment: @SteveC ok. I got it